# Why do we demand that symmetries commute with $S$-matrix?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, symmetry, s-matrix-theory

I am working in the context of Wightman Quantum Field Theory, and under a symmetry group I understand a group together with a unitary projective representation on the projective Hilbert space, unitary meaning that inner products of all unit length representatives are preserved.

Now in Lopuszanskis book "An introduction to symmetry and supersymmetry in quantum field theory" on page 116 it is stated that only those symmetries commuting with the $S$-matrix are of interest, since we would else have different $S$-matrices for all transformed fields. Can someone give an explanation why this would be a problem?

Comment: For those without access to the book, the author is considering global transformations on fields $\phi$. For the transformed fields ($phi_g$), he writes the transformation of an "in" field to an "out" field using an S-matrix specific for each transformed field (i.e. an S-matrix that depends on the parameter(s) $g$). What he says below in that page is interesting: "Taking a pragmatic attitude, we would like to work with only one single S-matrix and not with an infinitely large family of them [...]. Then it's reasonable to demand that the S-matrix commutes with the group elements.".